# grep -r "string" * error: unrecognized option `--DIRAC3LE--'?

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I'm trying to use grep in my Mac Terminal window, and it's giving me that error message.  What is that?  I've never seen it before and Google is not helping.  Looks like DIRAC3LE is some kind of Mac audio plugin -- but why would that interfere with grep?!? Thanks for any help!

Comment: `grep -r "string" -- *` will prevent filenames from being treated as options.

Comment: That said, questions about using `grep` from the command line (or otherwise not specific to scripting) are a better fit for [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) than StackOverflow. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, note the criterion "unique to software development" being *and*ed into the other bullet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell is probably expanding * and there is a '--DIRAC3LE--' in the working directory. `grep` is then confusing the leading -- with command line options.

Try using

```
grep -r "string" .
```

This will recursively search for everything in the working directory.

Also try using "--" before the *. POSIX commands use this to indicate the end of the command line options to prevent such ambiguity (see comments for a reference).

Comment: Re: "many tools" -- honoring `--` as an end-of-options sigil is #10 in the [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) As the [POSIX specification for `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) explicitly specifies that "The grep utility shall conform to XBD Utility Syntax Guidelines", this behavior is mandatory.

Comment: Indeed. I had a quick look at an online mac grep manpage, but I didn't find that.